# Identify leads which does not have a matching campaign member

Tags: soql, leads, campaign-member

Due to a trigger bypass method, few leads created in our org missed to create the corresponding campaign member.
I need to find out the leads which does not have a corresponding campaign member.
Could someone suggest a better approach to filter the leads which does not have a matching campaign member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Left Anti Join SOQL query will help you

```
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Lead 
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT LeadId 
                 FROM CampaignMember 
                 WHERE Type = 'Lead')
```

For more information, refer [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)